# CiviMail - KCFinder upload issues - "You must be logged in with proper permissions", Chrome only

Tags: civimail, kcfinder

We are having some issues being unable to upload images to CiviMail. This only seems to happen on Chrome (52 on OSX, but perhaps not exclusively), while the same user has no issues in Safari. Seems to affect some users all the time, but not others with similar setups, and other users intermittently.

These two messages are logged for user Anonymous (though the user is obviously logged in):

LOCATION    https://secure.wildsight.ca/sites/secure.wildsight.ca/modules/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/upload.php?cms=civicrm&type=images&CKEditor=crmUiId_1&CKEditorFuncNum=3&langCode=en
REFERRER
MESSAGE $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [message] => You must be logged in with proper permissions to edit, add, or delete uploaded images. [code] => )

LOCATION    https://secure.wildsight.ca/sites/secure.wildsight.ca/modules/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/upload.php?cms=civicrm&type=images&CKEditor=crmUiId_1&CKEditorFuncNum=3&langCode=en
REFERRER
MESSAGE $backTrace = #0 /var/www/civicrm/4.6/CRM/Core/Error.php(364): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) #1 /var/www/civicrm/4.6/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php(68): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You must be logged in with proper permissions to edit, add, or delete uploade...") #2 /var/www/civicrm/4.6/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php(140): checkAuthentication() #3 /var/www/civicrm/4.6/packages/kcfinder/core/bootstrap.php(39): require("/var/www/civicrm/4.6/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php") #4 /var/www/civicrm/4.6/packages/kcfinder/upload.php(15): require("/var/www/civicrm/4.6/packages/kcfinder/core/bootstrap.php") #5 {main}

Civi 4.6.18, Drupal 7.44

Comment: Turns out that one user in question has their IP address changing very frequently (on a timespan of minutes) and has now found the same problem in Safari.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in the Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.9.1. After applying this patch also it is not working. It is giving this error. Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. You must be logged in with proper permissions to edit, add, or delete uploaded images.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in civicrm 4.6 drupal 7.50.

I made this patch to fix the issue, i hope that will be useful.
https://github.com/rubofvil/civicrm-packages/commit/563a422384ae20cc0077225bebb748813fa6b22d.patch

Comment: https://github.com/rubofvil/civicrm-packages/commit/24a39648a2660e26baf8fe463d6a34a32d593548.patch